# Noun for brave person

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word, a noun, that denotes a brave person. Appropriate contexts in which I would like to use this word would be war, general conflicts in life and situations which demand a firm, bold person.

As a side note, *hero* and *daredevil* do not reflect what I am looking for.

Example sentences:

"What did you do, ____, rather than stare?" -obviously ironically

"He is a ____ that managed the stress of war easily."

Comment: Why doesn't hero work? Did you consider its synonyms, like lionheart?

Comment: What's wrong with *hero* that *hero* (or *daredevil*) do not work for you? Please explain more about what you are looking for.

Comment: Because hero means _"a person who is admired for having done something very brave or having achieved something great"_ (source: Cambridge Dictionary) and _"A person who is admired for their courage, outstanding achievements, or noble qualities"_ (source: Oxford Dictionary). I am not looking for someone who is admired or who is known for this kind of feats. Moreover, I am looking for a noun that denotes just a brave person, not a brave person that did remarkable things.

Comment: In regards to daredevil, I am not looking for a noun that denotes _"a person who does dangerous things and takes risks"_ (source: Cambridge Dictionary), but rather someone who has the guts, the nerve to confront certain common situations, such as conflicts in a war. Moreover, the word daredevil strongly implies that the said person is actively looking for such dangerous situations, like certain people that do car races or extreme sports.

Comment: Does [braveheart](https://www.wordnik.com/words/braveheart) work? You should really give an example sentence where you would like to use this word.

Comment: @alwayslearning Cheers! _Braveheart_ does indeed fit the description of what I am looking for. Please leave it as an answer. I will mark it in a short while if I do not receive any other similar answers.

Comment: I'm thinking adjectives might fit better: intrepid, stoic. Or perhaps a "literary" allusion proper noun might work, depending on audience: Rambo, Hercules, James Bond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That person is a ***braveheart***.

> "What did you do, ***braveheart***, rather than stare?" -obviously ironically
>
> "He is a ***braveheart*** that managed the stress of war easily."

Wordnik:

> **[braveheart](https://www.wordnik.com/words/braveheart)**
>
> from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License
>
> *n*. A brave person.